# sendmail: fatal: -n option not supported

Tags: linux, sendmail

I am trying to send a mail in Linux using the `sendmail` command:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/sh
echo "Mailing started"
export mail_lst="abc@xyz.com"
export mail_sub='test mail'
export mail_bdy='Please Review the Data'    
/usr/lib/sendmail -t -n  -oi<<!
From:Team
To:${mail_lst}
Subject:${mail_sub}    
${mail_bdy}    
Regards,
abc
echo "mailing completed"
```

But I am receiving the following error:

```
sendmail: fatal: -n option not supported
```

Comment: Perhaps look at `man sendmail`? What did you expect.

Comment: Well, I think the script is paste&copy from somewhere and the aksker did not yet check the details. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Program named "sendmail" merely may be provided by another MTA software package (e.g. Postfix or Exim) for purposes of merely email sending.  In such cases "sendmail look alike" may support reduced set of "native" command line options.

BTW "man sendmail" (sendmail by sendmail.org) states `-n     Don't do aliasing`.

Comment: I have tried man sendmail . There it is showing as -n (ignored)
Backwards compatibility.

Comment: "Differences" between man pages and real implementation are not unknown.  If you want more "detailed" help then post name of Linux distribution you use and name of package providing your "sendmail look alike".

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, and it probably should go without saying, but... considering that no answers have been marked good or approved or anything...

If your "sendmail" doesn't support -n, try running sendmail without the -n.  The old sendmail I used to use way back when I used sendmail's -n option wasn't very significant.  According to the man page apparently had, your sendmail replacement's coder thought even less of it than me.  (IMHO, it was a useful debugging tool - but using it in a script suggests there were issues with the server's mail configuration that weren't getting fixed.)